# Proof simplification

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I am  tasked with proving the following:

$$\varnothing   - A =   \varnothing  $$

**My Attempt :**

Assume there exist $x  \in $$\varnothing   - A $ then

$$ x \in \varnothing   - A \Rightarrow x \in \varnothing \land  x \notin  A$$

However  by definition of the  empty set,  the cannot exist $x$ such that $x \in \varnothing $
and hence there doesn't exist a $x$ s.t $x \in \varnothing - A$

Is this correct? If so is there a more concise/rigorous way to represent this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right, another way can be : If $A$ and $B$ are such that $A\subseteq B$, then $A\setminus B=\phi$. Since $\phi$ is a subset of every set, your question follows.

Answer (score 1):

It looks correct. One could also say that $\varnothing - A$ must be a subset of $\varnothing$, and hence the empty set itself.

Answer (score 0):

With bother with elements? 
Another solution might be
$$
B-A \subseteq B
\\
\emptyset\subseteq A
$$for every $A$ and $B$.
It gives you 
$$
\emptyset-A \subseteq \emptyset
,\,\,\,
\emptyset\subseteq \emptyset-A\implies \emptyset=\emptyset-A $$

Comment: Why bother? Because it's a very rudimentary tool; because it helps you learn to prove things by using their definition; and because sometimes it's good to do things the long way.

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Here is just another way to write your (correct) proof.

For any $\;x\;$,

$$\calc
x \in \varnothing - A
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;-\;$}
x \in \varnothing \land x \not\in A
\calcop{\equiv}{definition of $\;\varnothing\;$}
\text{false} \land x \not\in A
\calcop{\equiv}{logic: simplify}
\text{false}
\endcalc$$

By the definition of $\;\varnothing\;$, this is equivalent to $\;\varnothing - A = \varnothing\;$.